# Log-moneyness definition

Tags: options, monte-carlo, derivatives, call, quants

Define the time-0 log-moneyness of a call on stock $S$ with strike $K$ and expiry $T$ to be:

$$\log(S(0)\exp(rT)/K)$$

What does it mean for the strikes K to be at-the-log-moneyness?? I guessed this but i don't think it is right:

$$\log(K) = \log(S(0)\exp(rT)/K)$$

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it means K=S(0)*exp(rt), so that log moneyness is zero.

Comment: This would be my guess as well.

Comment: Note this is the same as at-the-money-forward